# How do I remove an item from localStorage array?I have

Tags: javascript

I have an array stored in localStorage. How can I remove the value of an array and save it in localStorage again?

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
localStorage.setItem("cars", JSON.stringify(cars));

let modifiedCars = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cars")).splice(0, 1)

// How do I remove cars[0] from the array and store it back into localStorage?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to remove the element by using `.filter()`;

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
localStorage.setItem("cars", JSON.stringify(cars));

let modifiedCars = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cars")).filter(el => el!= "Saab")

localStorage.setItem("cars", JSON.stringify(modifiedCars ));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but every time I try to use filter, it gives me this TypeError: localStorage.getItem(...).filter is not a function

Comment: @hiphopfeels `localStorage.getItem` returns a string, filter is on array prototype; we'd used it on `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cars"))` not the `.get` of `localstorage`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand can you maybe explain differently?

Comment: @hiphopfeels `"randomString".filter()` throws error; but `[].filter()` works fine; and  that `JSON.parse()` will return an return an array

Comment: Okay, this is exactly what I was looking for. My problem was that I didn't use JSON.parse(). Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` is a simple string-based storage. In order to remove an item, you need to read it (like you did), remove it (like you did) and store it again:

```js
localStorage.setItem('cars', JSON.stringify(modifiedCars));
```

Comment: Ok but how do I set this localStorage to "cars"?

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick :)